# How do I scrape information in a modal box

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is the URL I am trying to scrape:
https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2023/session_search.cfm

I have to scrape the data behind each session. For example, if you click the first session *"
Food, Mood, and the Microbiome – the Gut-Brain Axis: Moving Beyond the Monoamine Neurotransmitter Hypothesis and Toward Understanding the Holobiome"* A modal box will appear. I have to scrape this.

Here is the code I have currently written, but it crashes after it clicks on a link

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
url = 'https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2023/session_search.cfm'
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
test = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.session-title')


for session in test:
    print(session)
    time.sleep(3)
    session.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    test2 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '//.col-sm-12 col-md-12')
    driver.back()
```

How can I loop through each session, click on the session, scrape the data that appears on the modal box, and do this for all 500 sessions? (Only 50 appear at a time on a page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to achieve your wanted result. 
I removed the time.sleep() calls and implemented Explicit Waits so it's more efficient and doesn't crash when elements don't load fast enough. 
The try/except block is there so it doesn't break when the modal gets closed too slowly and blocks another element from being opened, and if it does it just retries it again instead of crashing.
If you have any questions about the code don't hesitate to ask :)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

url = 'https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2023/session_search.cfm'
pages = 12
descriptions = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

driver.get(url)

for page in range(pages):
    sessions = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.session-title')))
    for session in sessions:
        while True:
            try:
                session.click()
                break
            except ElementClickInterceptedException:
                continue
        description_text = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.col-sm-12.col-md-12'))).text
        descriptions.append(description_text)
        close_btn = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.close'))).click()

    next_page_btn = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.next'))).click()

print(descriptions)
```

Comment: Great thanks, your code provided a good template that I was able to modify. A quick question. Do you know how you would scrape the class 'session-track'chip'? I keep finding 131 items per session, when it should only be a handful. Same thing for the speakers section, it is only scraping the first two speakers.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to scrape using ```.session-track-chip```? As i see these are the "tags" for each session like "General Session" etc. and 131 items seems to be correct. Also thanks for accepting my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Do it like you would by hand. write a script that scrapes all the links on the page (all the a-tags that have an id that starts with session-title-), call .click() on those elements.
then a modal appears, get it by it's classname: modal-content
after you've done that, get the modal dialogs close button by it's class names too: 'close session-close text-light float-right'
loop until you've done that for all the links.
after that, get the pagina buttons at the bottom of the page by class name:
paginate_button
after you've done that, check which button has the class named "current" also, click the one after that.
Then, do this entire thing again, and again, until there's no more "paginate_buttons" after the "current" button.